# Error: can not find this simbol en concatenación de string

Tags: string

Estoy trabajando con Android Studio Hedgehog y he actualizado la app a la versión 34 de Android. Antes estaba con la versión Giraffe y la 33 de Android.
Ahora, con estas nuevas versiones, cuando intento concatenar dos strings me encuentro con el siguiente error:

```
    error: cannot find symbol
                String name = na + " Smith";
                                 ^
  symbol:   method makeConcatWithConstants(Lookup,String,MethodType,String)
  location: interface StringConcatFactory
```

'na' es una variable que contiene un string. No reconoce el símbolo + para concatenar strings.

¿Ha cambiado algo en Android 34 o en el Hedgehog para que esto ocurra? Os quedo agradecido por las respuestas.

Comment: Buenas, para consultar de un error, se necesitan 2 cosas, el error, y el fragmento de código donde sucede el error. Visita [mre] para más información, y de paso [ask] para entender como realizar una pregunta.

Comment: Si leyeras la pregunta verías que el código está en el error que lanza Android Studio. Simplemente en cualquier código dónde concateno dos strings me da ese error, creo que no es difícil de entender...

Comment: La solución está en este enlace de la página en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74529429/cannot-find-symbol-error-from-makeconcatwithconstants

Comment: nadie ah dicho que no se entienda, solo te menciono como se realiza una pregunta en el sitio. Y puedes ver exactamente que la respuesta encontrada, hace lo que deberías hacer tu. La respuesta enlazada tiene ambas cosas, el error, y el código en donde ocurre el error. La guia de [mre] enlazada explica esto de buen modo. Probablemente hubieras recibido una respuesta de algún dev de android más rápido al haber seguido esas guías que te mande. NOTA* la pregunta enlazada está mejor hecha, pero fijate que de todos modos, solicitan las dependencias.